# TableView (search results table view) scrolls unexpectedly sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am working on an app, which has implements a Search Display Controller. The search results table view, doesn't behave right all the time, and I'm trying to solve this issue from a few days. Here is a screen recording of the behavior.

[image: scroll Issue in search results table view]

I'm not modifying the frame or bounds of the table view. I'm only resigning first responder when there is no text in the search field, and calling the `[searchDisplayController setActive: animated: ]` method.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please check your cell allocation on cellforrowatindex path method , allocate new cell if it required otherwise simply re-use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, btw I am reusing the cells. I don't think there are any unused cells there, the tableview just scrolls infinitely. There are no cells below the visible cells.

Comment: do not use search bar controller.. use simple search bar and display it in tableview

Comment: @QualityCoder, I understand what you are saying, but what about in viewcontrollers where I do not have a tableview, in those screens, how do you suggest I should bring the search functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of setting the scrollIndicatorInsets and contentInsets of the searchResultsTableView when the keyboard hides, putting it within the 'willShowSearchResultsTableView:' delegate method fixed it for me:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by using my own TableView instead of SearchResultsDisplayController's table view. Placed a new tableview on top of my previous tableview, and showing and hiding the search table view based on the delegates of the Search Bar (textDidChange).

I adopted this workaround, as I failed to solve the mysteries of layout problems in SearchResultsTableView.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting what seems to be a very similar behaviour, but it only happened when running in the device (iPhone or iPad), but not in the simulator (both in iOS 8, Xcode 6.0.1, using Swift).

For some reason, when inputting a search text the `contentInset.bottom` and `scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom` of my `searchResultsTableView` didn't return to its original value after dismissing the keyboard. Each time the keyboard was shown and then dismissed, this value would increase by the keyboard's height and the space would get increasingly larger. I don't know what causes this, as I never fiddle with insets in the code. I'm suspecting it is some weird constraint going haywire, but I couldn't find it.

What solved for me was to programatically set the bottom insets to zero, whenever the keyboard was dismissed:

```
searchController.searchResultsTableView.contentInset.bottom = 0
searchController.searchResultsTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 0
```

I know this is only a workaround. Hope it helps in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing very similar to @ricardoaraujo, but find that when I scroll back down to the bottom of the list, the last few cells are off the bottom of the screen (about 200px worth, therefore 1 x keyboard.height).

The frame of the searchResultsTableView is perfect (checked by both logging and using the new Debug View Hierarchy mode), and the contentInset is set to UIEdgeInsetsZero.

You'll probably therefore notice the same thing, but short of creating your own UITableView to display the results (as in @Vignesh's answer), there doesn't seem to be a nice way around it.

This does not happen on iOS7, so hopefully will be fixed in iOS8.0.3. Will check radar.

Answer (score 0):

@Vignesh good that you got your problem solved, but `UISearchDisplayController` does that for us. It's true that it is a keyboard missing calculation issue, so I just had to set the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` back to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` when my keyboard goes way.

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, didHideSearchResultsTableView tableView: UITableView) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, willShowSearchResultsTableView tableView: UITableView) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    let tableView = self.searchController.searchResultsTableView
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

It's just another workaround, but it's working well so far on iOS7 +

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, willShowSearchResultsTableView table: UITableView!) -> Void {
    table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    table.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Based on answer of @user2795503